# JS/Vue - Returning promises async problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

Hello and thanks for your time reading my question.

I have a Vue component, call it 'interactiveChart'. On mounted (in specific order as shown below) i do the following:

1. Initialize my stuff (db manager, tool manager etc. etc.)
2. Calling ***this.run();*** to get my data for the first time. [***this.run();*** calls ***this.fetch();*** which returns a *Promise*, based on which i sort my data in the highchart, putting the data in series etc etc. I just handle the logic. So it is like this:

   - run() ->
   - (inside run) this.fetch->
   - then-> -logic goes here- || catch-> -handling error- ->
   - (inside run again) this.render() which calls the render function that as you can imagine it renders the chart.
3. So far so good. So, we're still in mounted, after the initialization and the this.run() call for the first time, i have some event handlers in there (they work fine) that they listen for specific events. After the event listeners i run this.render() again, because some of the events may change the chart options (add another axis etc etc). **BUT**. The data that we initially parsed are based on a specific id. let's say id 1. There are some events that may ask for data for another id, let's say 2,3 and 4. That means i have to run this.run() again for 2,3 and 4. So instead of running this.run() for one id only, i use an array called idNotations to store all the ids needed to parse the data for. And i do a for of loop in this.run() to fetch the data for every id. My problem is the following:

the function this.render() inside this.run() will run 4 times if i give 4 ids (so i keep seeing the chart reloading for 1-2 seconds) then it shows correctly. the data are being shown just fine. its just that render runs befefore the fetch all the data of ids, for each one of them. what i want is to make it run only once, after all the promises have finished. if i move the render() outside of the for of loop it wont show (because run() is not async, it just calls fetch to avoid code duplication. How i can resolve this problem?

```
  mounted() {
console.log('Function Call: mounted()');

//Initialization
this.selectedTimeSpan = timeSpansArray.find((el) => el.timeSpan == '5Y');
this.mdg2Client = globalMdg2ClientFactory.createMdg2Client();
this.highchartOptions = this.getHighchartsOptions();
this.run();

/**
 * Events Below
 */

//When Timespan Changes
this.$root.$on('chartZoom', (payload) => {
  console.log('[Event Emitted] - Timespan Changed');
  this.interactiveChart.showLoading('Loading Data..');
  this.selectedTimeSpan = timeSpansArray.find(
    (el) => el.timeSpan === payload.timeSpan
  );
  this.run();
});

//When Chart Type Changes
this.$root.$on('chart-type', (payload) => {
  console.log('[Event Emitted] - Chart Type/Data Changed', payload);

  //Reseting step
  this.hasStep = false;

  //Need yMin in OHLC and Candlestick chart types
  let yMin = toolsManager.calculateMin(
    this.highchartOptions.series[0].data
  );

  //Swap between chart types
  switch (payload['chart-type']) {
    case 'step':
      this.hasStep = true;
    case 'mountain':
      this.highchartOptions.series[0].type = null;
      this.highchartOptions.chart.type = 'area';
      this.highchartOptions.yAxis[0].min = yMin;
      break;
    case 'candlestick':
      this.highchartOptions.series[0].type = 'candlestick';
      break;
    case 'ohlc':
      this.highchartOptions.series[0].type = 'ohlc';
      break;
    default:
      this.highchartOptions.series[0].type = 'line';
      break;
  }
  this.highchartOptions.series[0].step = this.hasStep;

  //Select performance
  if (payload['chart-perf'] === 'axisTrue') {
    this.highchartOptions.plotOptions.series.compare = 'percent';
    this.highchartOptions.yAxis[0].min = null;
    this.highchartOptions.yAxis[0].labels.format = '{value:.2f}%';
  } else {
    this.highchartOptions.plotOptions.series.compare = null;
    this.highchartOptions.yAxis[0].labels.format = null;
  }

  //Benchmark selected
  if (payload['add-benchmark']) {
    if (payload['add-benchmark'].length > 0) {
      this.interactiveChart.showLoading('Loading Data..');
      this.benchmarks = payload['add-benchmark'];
      this.cleanIds();
      this.renderFlag = false;
      this.run();
      this.renderFlag = true;
    } else {
      this.cleanSeries();
      this.cleanBenchmarks();
      this.cleanIds();
    }
  }

  //Indicators selected
  if (payload['indicators']) {
    if (payload['indicators'].length > 0) {
      this.interactiveChart.showLoading('Loading Data..');
      this.indicators = payload['indicators'];
      this.sortIndicators();
    } else {
      while (this.indicators.length > 0) {
        this.indicators.pop();
      }
      this.cleanIndicators();
    }
  }

  this.render(this.highchartOptions);
});





   //Fetching Data from server
fetch(timeSpan, idToFetchFrom) {
  console.log(`Function Call: fetch()`);
  this.timespanDates = toolsManager.calculateDates(
    timeSpan.totalTimeRange.days
  );

  const data = {
    id: idToFetchFrom,
    quality: this.priceQuality,
    range: {
      start: this.timespanDates[0],
      end: this.timespanDates[1],
    },
  };

  const meta = {
    pagination: {
      limit: timeSpan.totalTimeRange.days,
    },
  };

  //If it is 1D or 5D
  if (this.selectedTimeSpan.getIntradayData) {
    data.type = 'trade';
    data.quality = 'DLY';
    data.range.start.concat('T00:00:00.000Z');
    data.range.end.concat('T07:00:00.000Z');
    data.granularity = timeSpan.granularity;

    timeSpan.timeSpan === '1D'
      ? (meta.pagination.limit *= 24 * 60) //Days * 24 Hours * 60 (1 minute granularity so 60*1M===1H)
      : (meta.pagination.limit *= 24 * 6); //Days * 24 Hours * 6 (10 minutes granularity so 6*10M===1H)

    return this.mdg2Client.requestEndpoint(
      this.requestMethod,
      '/api/v1/prices/timeSeries/intraday/subsample/list',
      { data, meta }
    );
  } else {
    return this.mdg2Client.requestEndpoint(
      this.requestMethod,
      this.endpoint,
      { data, meta }
    );
  }
},


//Handling the response from the server
run() {
  console.log('Function Call: run()');
  this.sortIndicators();
  for (let id of this.idsToFetchData) {
    console.log(`run(): ${id}`);
    this.fetch(this.selectedTimeSpan, id)
      .then((res) => {
        const { data } = res;
        let prices = [];

        //we get an array subsamples when we use the endpoint for 1D and 5D, but an array called prices for the rest of the timespans
        this.selectedTimeSpan.getIntradayData
          ? (prices = data.subsamples)
          : (prices = data.prices);
        let priceSeries = [];
        this.volumeSeries = [];
        /**
         * Tick Interval can be either 1 or 5. We get the lowest price each day or every fifth one.
         */
        if (this.selectedTimeSpan.tickInterval === 1) {
          for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            let xData = null;
            this.selectedTimeSpan.getIntradayData
              ? (xData = Math.floor(new Date(prices[i].time).getTime()))
              : (xData = Math.floor(new Date(prices[i].date).getTime()));
            priceSeries[i] = {
              x: xData,
              open: prices[i].first,
              high: prices[i].high,
              low: prices[i].low,
              close: prices[i].last,
              y: prices[i].last,
              volume: prices[i].tradingVolume,
            };
            if (id == this.$props.idNotation) {
              this.volumeSeries[i] = {
                x: xData,
                y: prices[i].tradingVolume,
              };
            }
          }
        } else {
          let j = 0;
          for (
            let i = 4;
            i < prices.length;
            i += this.selectedTimeSpan.tickInterval
          ) {
            priceSeries[j] = {
              x: Math.floor(new Date(prices[i].date).getTime()),
              open: prices[i].first,
              high: prices[i].high,
              low: prices[i].low,
              close: prices[i].last,
              y: prices[i].last,
              volume: prices[i].tradingVolume,
            };
            if (id == this.$props.idNotation) {
              this.volumeSeries[j] = {
                x: Math.floor(new Date(prices[i].date).getTime()),
                y: prices[i].tradingVolume,
              };
            }
            j++;
          }
        }

        if (id == this.$props.idNotation) {
          this.highchartOptions.series[0].data = priceSeries;
          this.highchartOptions.series[1].data = this.volumeSeries;
        } else {
          this.benchmarks.forEach((benchmark) => {
            if (benchmark.id == id) {
              benchmark.data = priceSeries;
              this.highchartOptions.series.push(benchmark);
            }
          });
        }

        // this.sortIndicators(this.indicators);
        this.highchartOptions.xAxis.labels.format = `{value:${this.selectedTimeSpan.xAxisDateFormat}}`;
        console.log('look', this.renderFlag);
        if (this.renderFlag) this.render(this.highchartOptions);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('[ Caught Error ]', e);
      });
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks robby for the reply, I updated my topic, (renderFlag is not working properly of course since it not async)

Comment: any chance that you make a codesandbox with the "4 times calling run()". because it's hard to get behind your code if you post so much.

Comment: I will try to implement it in codesandbox yes.

Comment: It sounds like you need to the promises to Promise.all() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using Promise.all() as suggested by recoilnetworks. Thanks !